# Salesforce test class for controller extension

Tags: controller

I think I made the test in the right way, but coverage still 31%

```
public class ContractMilestoneInfoApex {
public List<Milestoneinfo> MSIList {set; get;}
public Milestoneinfo MSI {set; get;}
public List<Work_Order_Task__c> query {get; set;}
public String currentRecordId {get;set;}


public  ContractMilestoneInfoApex (ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    String url = ApexPages.currentPage().getURL();
    currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
    MSIList = new List<Milestoneinfo>();
    query = new List<Work_Order_Task__c>();

    query = [select Name,Task_Type__c,Man_Days_Estimated__c,Man_Days_Actual__c,(select  Resource_Name__c,Estimated_Man_Days__c,Actual_Man_Days__c from Resources__r) from Work_Order_Task__c where Milestone__c = :currentRecordId];

    Integer n = 1;
    for(Work_Order_Task__c m: query){
        MSI = new Milestoneinfo();
        MSI.num = n++;
        MSI.name = m.Name;
        MSI.tasktype = m.Task_Type__c;
        MSI.estimated_MD = m.Man_Days_Estimated__c;
        MSI.actual_MD = m.Man_Days_Actual__c;
        MSI.RESList = new List<Resourceinfo>();

        for(Resource__c res: m.Resources__r){
            Resourceinfo resinfo = new Resourceinfo();
            resinfo.res_name = res.Resource_Name__c;
            resinfo.res_estimated_MD = res.Estimated_Man_Days__c;
            resinfo.res_actual_MD = res.Actual_Man_Days__c;

            MSI.RESList.add(resinfo);

        }

        MSIList.add(MSI);
    }
}

public class Milestoneinfo{
    public Integer num{get; set;}
    public String name{get; set;}
    public String tasktype{get; set;}
    public Double estimated_MD{get; set;}
    public Double actual_MD{get; set;}
    public List<Resourceinfo> RESList{get; set;}
}

public class Resourceinfo{
    public String res_name{get; set;}
    public Double res_estimated_MD{get; set;}
    public Double res_actual_MD{get; set;}
}
```

}

```
    @isTest
    public class ContractMilestoneInfoApexTest{
    static testMethod void myTest() {

    list<Milestoneinfo> MSIList = new List<Milestoneinfo>();

    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'TEST Account12345');
    insert acc;

    Contract contr = new Contract();
    contr.Contract_Title__c  = 'Test Contract';
    contr.StartDate  = system.today();
    contr.EndDate = system.today() + 365;
    contr.Received_Date__c = system.today();
    contr.Contract_Auto_Number__c = 1038;
    contr.Contract__c = 'Draft';
    contr.AccountId = acc.id;
    upsert contr;

    PO_Invoices__c INO = new PO_Invoices__c(); 
    INO.Status__c = 'Planned';
    INO.Notes__c = 'SDP Preparation Description';
    INO.Issue_Date__c = Date.Today() + 10;
    INO.Paid_Amount__c = 0;
    INO.Total_Amount__c = 400000;
    INO.Choose_Technical_Leader__c = 'Primary Technical Leader'; 
    INO.PO__c = contr.id;
    INO.Technical_Work_Status__c = 'Delivered';
    upsert INO;

    Work_Order__c wo = new Work_Order__c();
    wo.Client__c = acc.id;
    wo.Status__c = 'New';
    wo.Start_Date__c = Date.Today()+1;
    wo.End_Date__c = Date.Today()+4;
    wo.Type__c = 'Service Request';
    upsert wo;

   Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = '!Changi - System Admin'];
   ID UserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
   User u = new User(
       Alias = 'Khan',
       Email = 'test@gistec.com',
       EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
       LastName = 'Test',
       LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
       LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
       TimeZoneSidKey='Asia/Dubai',
       ProfileId = p.Id,
       UserName='test_farman_ali@gistec.com',
       Resource_Manager__c = UserId
   );
   INSERT u;

   Work_Order_Task__c SDRSubTask3 = new Work_Order_Task__c();
   SDRSubTask3.Name = 'test sub task';
    SDRSubTask3.Task_Type__c = 'Technical Lead Coordination / Status Reporting';
    SDRSubTask3.Man_Days_Estimated__c = 100;
    SDRSubTask3.Man_Days_Actual__c = 100;
   SDRSubTask3.Work_Order__c = wo.id;
   SDRSubTask3.Status__c = 'Planned';
   SDRSubTask3.Approved_by_Client__c = false;
   SDRSubTask3.Milestone__c = INO.id;
   upsert SDRSubTask3;



   Resource__c  r1 = new Resource__c();
   r1.Work_Order_Task__c = SDRSubTask3.id;
   r1.Proposed_Employee__c = u.id;
   r1.Employee__c = u.id;
   r1.Deducted_Man_Days__c = 100.0;
   r1.Estimated_Man_Days__c = 100.0;
   r1.Actual_Man_Days__c = 100.0;
   upsert r1;



   Work_Order_Task__c SDRSubTask4 = new Work_Order_Task__c();
   SDRSubTask4.Name = 'test sub task1';
     SDRSubTask3.Task_Type__c = 'Technical Lead Coordination / Status Reporting';
    SDRSubTask3.Man_Days_Estimated__c = 100;
    SDRSubTask3.Man_Days_Actual__c = 100;
   SDRSubTask4.Work_Order__c = wo.id;
   SDRSubTask4.Milestone__c = INO.id;
   SDRSubTask4.Status__c = 'In Progress';
   upsert SDRSubTask4; 

   Resource__c  r2 = new Resource__c();
   r2.Work_Order_Task__c = SDRSubTask4.id;
   r2.Proposed_Employee__c = u.id;
   r2.Employee__c = u.id;
   r2.Deducted_Man_Days__c = 100.0;
   r2.Estimated_Man_Days__c = 100.0;
   r2.Actual_Man_Days__c = 100.0;
   upsert r2;


     Test.startTest();      
     PageReference pageRef = Page.ContractMilestoneInfo;
     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(INO.id));
     Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
     ContractMilestoneInfoApex accopp = new ContractMilestoneInfoApex (new ApexPages.StandardController(INO));
     Test.stopTest();


 }

 public class Milestoneinfo{
    public Integer num{get; set;}
    public String name{get; set;}
    public String tasktype{get; set;}
    public Double estimated_MD{get; set;}
    public Double actual_MD{get; set;}
    public List<Resourceinfo> RESList{get; set;}
}

public class Resourceinfo{
    public String res_name{get; set;}
    public Double res_estimated_MD{get; set;}
    public Double res_actual_MD{get; set;}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the ID parameter isn't making it to the page properly.  Try replacing the following line:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(INO.id));
```

with:

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', INO.id);
```